# Integration step need some explanation (Calculus)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$\displaystyle{\frac15\int_0^1\left[v(1+v^2)^5-v^{11}\right]dv=\frac 15\left[\frac 12\cdot\frac 16(1+v^2)^6-\frac{1}{12}v^{12}\right]_0^1}$

Can someone explain how to get the RHS from LHS. It's the first term after the integral sign that I am confused about.

Thanks.

Comment: Make the substitution  $u=1+v^2$. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: For the first term, they are using the substitution $u=1+v^2$ to get $\int\frac{1}{2}u^5 du$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that integration is linear so:
$$\int x(1+x^2)^5-x^{11} \, \operatorname{d}\!x = \int x(1+x^2)^5 \, \operatorname{d}\!x - \int x^{11} \, \operatorname{d}\!x$$

Hopefully you already know that 
$$\int x^{11} \, \operatorname{d}\!x = \frac{1}{12}x^{12}+C$$
You need to show that 
$$\int x(1+x^2)^5 \, \operatorname{d}\!x = \frac{1}{12}(1+x^2)^6 + C$$

We can perform this [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution). If $u=1+x^2$ then $\operatorname{d}\!u = 2x\,\operatorname{d}\!x$. Hence
$$\int x(1+x^2)^5 \, \operatorname{d}\!x = \int u^5 \cdot \tfrac{1}{2}\,\operatorname{d}\!u = \frac{1}{2}\int u^5 \, \operatorname{d}\!u = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot u^6 + C$$
Recalling that $u=1+x^2$, we may conclude that
$$\int x(1+x^2)^5 \, \operatorname{d}\!x = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot (1+x^2)^6 + C$$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac15\int_0^1\left[v(1+v^2)^5-v^{11}\right]dv=\frac15\int_0^1\left[\frac12(1+v^2)^5-\frac12(v^2)^5\right]d(v^2)$

Comment: Ah, very nice trick! +1

Answer (score 1):

The first integral is being done by substitution. Put $u = v^2$, then $du = 2v\,dv$ so

$$\int_0^1 v(1 + v^2)^5 dv = \int_0^1 u^5(du/2) $$

I think you can see the rest.

Comment: Do you really mean to have two lots of $du$ in the RHS? What is
$$\int u^5 \, \frac{du}{2} \, du \ \ ?$$

Comment: Yerright Fly by Night. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

$$v(1+v^2)^5-v^{11}=\left(\frac 12\cdot\frac 16(1+v^2)^6-\frac{1}{12}v^{12}\right)'$$
$$\int v(1+v^2)^5dv-\int v^{11}dv=I_1-I_2$$
$$I_2=v^{12}/12$$
$$I_1=\int v(1+v^2)^5dv$$
$1+v^2=t,vdv=(1/2)dt$

$$I_1=(1/2)\int t^5dt=(1/2)(1/6)t^6$$

Comment: The question asked how to "*get the RHS from LHS*" and not get from the RHS to the LHS.

Comment: Isn't that what this answer hints to, @FlybyNight ?  The answer shows the RHS is the LHS's primitive (without the limits, of course), and then the Fundamental Theorem of (integral) Calculus. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio The way I read it is that the OP is unable to find $\int v(1+v^2)^5 \, \operatorname{d}\!v$. Please re-read the OP and see if you agree. IMHO, there's a big difference between finding

$$\int \frac{\operatorname{d}\!x}{1+x^2}$$

and checking that

$$\frac{\operatorname{d}\!}{\operatorname{d}\!x} \arctan x = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: @FlybyNight, perhaps you're right and the OP wanted to know the *how* . Anyway, the answerer above extended his answer, though the one I liked the most is nadia-liza's below.